# Any method in PostgreSQL to create mutiple index entries on the same datum

Tags: postgresql, indexing, gis, postgis

I'm indexing some spatial objects in PG and at this time I'm using PG with PostGis to build a R-tree. However, some objects are too large to be indexed, so I want to first split them to smaller parts and index them by the smaller parts.

However, I read the document of Gist, and find that there is nowhere to split (in the index level) one datum unless I first split them in the original relation.

Is there any way so solve this problem in Gist? Or are there any other framework to solve this problem? Or why it's impossible under the PG?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to do with the index.

One option would be not to index the objects themselves, but a simplified version:

```
CREATE INDEX ON atable USING gist (st_simplify(geom, 1, TRUE));
```

And then use that as a pre-filter:

```
SELECT ... FROM atable
WHERE st_intersects(st_simplify(geom, 1, TRUE), GEOMETRY '...')
  AND st_intersects(geom, GEOMETRY '...');
```

That can use the index. The problem is that it could be that the simplified geometry does not intersect, so you could get false negatives in corner cases.